# How can I pass a body request in a GET request [ClojureScript]

Tags: clojurescript

I'm trying to pass a body request into a GET. No, it can't be parameters in the url, it doesn't work in this specific case, to endpoint must receive a request body even if it is a GET.

I tried using https://github.com/JulianBirch/cljs-ajax and https://github.com/day8/re-frame-http-fx with :body params, but none worked. Does someone here knows an alternative? Is for Clojurescript.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP specification says that GET requests should not have bodies.

Many HTTP client implementations — including those (`fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest`) built into browsers — **do not** allow you to set a body on GET requests.

Whatever client you are using must be such a client.

---

Change the server so it doesn't depend on behaviour the HTTP specification warns again.